# Another expression for "bend over backwards"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for another idiomatic expression for "bend over backwards" to help others.

Comment: Although idiom requests are on-topic on ELU (and not Linguistics, where this came from), the question needs a good deal more content. Please see the tag info for [phrase requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) for some general points for this type of question.

Comment: "Extend oneself" might be possible, as might "put oneself out" or "go the extra mile". I've also heard the highly colloquial "bust a gut" used quite often.

Comment: Go above and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

"Give the shirt off his/her back" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+shirt+off+back

> Fig. to give anything that is asked for, no matter the sacrifice
>   required. *Tom would give any of his old army buddies the shirt off his
>   back. You can always count on Mark when you're in trouble; he'd give
>   you the shirt off his back.*

"Generous to a fault"
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+a+fault

> Excessively, extremely, as in *He was generous to a fault*. This
>   phrase, always qualifying an adjective, has been so used since the
>   mid-1700s. Indeed, Oliver Goldsmith had this precise usage in The Life
>   of Richard Nash (1762).